# al querer crear un objeto recibo "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, clase, object

Tengo un programa que debe de simular un juego de cartas. La clase Deck es la encargada de crear la baraja y barajearla (objeto Naipe). Al intentar crear el objeto (solo se creara uno) me aparece el error del titulo.

Este es mi main y la clase Deck

```
import java.util.*;

public class Naipes {

public static void main() {

    //instancia de la clase principal para poder crear el objeto deck
    Naipes instancia = new Naipes();

    int cartas;
    int manos;
    Deck deck = new Deck(); //creacion del deck
    ArrayList<Mano> mesa = new ArrayList<Mano>(); // mesa contendra los objetos mano
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Cantidad de jugadores (manos) que hay en la mesa: ");
    manos = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\nCantidad de cartas que tendra cada mano: ");
    cartas = sc.nextInt();  

    if ((manos * cartas) > 52) {
        System.out.print("NO HAY SUFICIENTES CARTAS");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= manos; i++) {
        mesa.add(new Mano(i, cartas)); // el contador "i" representara el ID de la mano creada

        // loop que asigna los naipes a las manos
        for (int n = 0; n < manos; n++) {
    ((Mano) mesa.get(i-1)).naipes.add(Deck.baraja.remove(0));
        }
    }

}

private class Deck {

ArrayList<Naipe> baraja = new ArrayList<Naipe>();

    public Deck() {
    // lista que almacena los objetos naipe
    crearBaraja(this.baraja);
    barajearDeck(this.baraja);
    }

    private ArrayList<Naipe> crearBaraja(ArrayList baraja) {

        int suit = 0; //el palo del Naipe
        char signo;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            //loop crea naipes del 0 al 10
            for( int val = 2; val < 11; val++) {
                signo = (char)(val + '0');
                baraja.add(new Naipe(suit, val, signo));
            }

            // se crean naipes J, Q, R, A
            baraja.add(new Naipe(suit, 10, 'J'));
            baraja.add(new Naipe(suit, 10, 'Q'));
            baraja.add(new Naipe(suit, 10, 'R'));
            baraja.add(new Naipe(suit, 11, 'A'));

            suit++;
        }
    }

    private void barajearDeck(ArrayList baraja) {
        Collections.shuffle(baraja);
    }
}
```

si necesitan ver las clases Mano y Naipe aqui estan

```
private class Mano {

int ID;
ArrayList<Naipe> naipes = new ArrayList<Naipe>();
int numNaipes;

    public Mano (int identidad, int cantidad_naipes) {

        this.ID = identidad;
        this.numNaipes = cantidad_naipes;
    }

    public int suma() {

        int suma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.numNaipes; i++) {
            suma += this.naipes.get(i).darValor();
        }
        return suma;
    }

    public void impMano() {

        for (int i = 0; i < this.numNaipes; i++) {
            this.naipes.get(i).mostrar();
        }
    }

}

private class Naipe {

int valor;
char simbolo;
String mazo;

    private Naipe (int palo, int val, char signo) {
        this.valor = val;
        this.simbolo = signo;
        this.mazo = determinarMazo(palo);
    }

    private String determinarMazo(int palo) {

        String suit;

        if (palo == 0)
            suit = "Picas";
        else if (palo == 1)
            suit = "Diamantes";
        else if (palo == 2)
            suit = "Treboles";
        else 
            suit = "Corazones";

        return suit;
    }

    public int darValor() {
        return this.valor;
    }

    public void mostrar() {
        System.out.println(this.simbolo + " de " + this.mazo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues puede que solo te falte la palabra reservada `static` en las funciones que creaste.

**Ejemplo.**

```
private static ArrayList<Naipe> crearBaraja(ArrayList baraja) {

....
private static void barajearDeck(ArrayList baraja) {

....
```

Y asi en todos.

Comment: Ya lo habia intentado, el compilador me marca error al momento de hacer una referencia a algun objeto Naipe, estos estan ubicados dentro del objeto Deck

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que estás haciendo referencia a la clase `Deck` cuando entiendo que querías llamar al objeto `deck` instanciado aquí:

```
Deck deck = new Deck();
```

Cambia en este `for` `Deck` por `deck` (y de paso trata de nombrar variables mejor para evitar estos problemas)

```
 for (int n = 0; n < manos; n++) {
    ((Mano) mesa.get(i-1)).naipes.add(deck.baraja.remove(0));
 }
```

Además, en el método `crearBaraja` te falta devolver la `baraja`:

```
 return baraja;
```

Comment: Si hice un mal trabajo con las variables. Pero el error me lo da el momento de instanciar la clase Deck, no en el for (que ya corregi, gracias)

Answer (score 0):

---

Saludos, Luis César.

Lo que pasa es que la clase `Deck` no es una clase estática, sino una clase privada y tú estás queriendo accesarla de forma estática.

Dependiendo de lo que deseas realizar, podrías simplemente modificar tu clase `Deck` de esto:

```
private class Deck
```

A esto:

```
public static class Deck // también puede ser private static class
```

O bien, podrías declarar tu clase `Deck` en un archivo aparte de `Naipes`

Comment: El problema es que dentro de la clase Deck manejo objetos Naipe, que no son estaticos. Si hago la clase Deck estatica, entonces me marca error al momento de hacer referencia a los objetos Naipe dentro de la clase Deck

Comment: También deberías hacerlos estáticos para que te funcione correctamente. Sin embargo, en mi opinión no veo que sea la manera correcta de hacerlo, ¿por qué no creas una instancia de `Naipes` en tu método `main` y manipulas toda la lógica de tu programa desde tu clase `Naipes`? Es decir, colocar tu código dentro del constructor o en algún método de tu clase naipes.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes tus clases definidas de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Naipes {
    ...
    private class Deck {
        ...
    }
}
```

De esa forma `Deck` es una *inner class* de `Naipes` y solo puede existir como una referencia asociada a una instancia de `Naipes`.

En un metodo de instancia de `Naipes` puedes hacer:

```
Deck d = new Deck();
```

Pero en un método estático de `Naipes` tienes que especificar cual es la instancia de `Naipes` que contiene a Deck:

```
Naipes n = new Naipes();
Deck d = n.new Deck();
```

Luego, la recomendación por legibilidad en tu caso es no utilizar *inner classes*. En su lugar puedes usar *static nested class*:

```
public class Naipes {
    ...
    private static class Deck {
        ...
    }
}
```

O no usar un mismo archivo para todas tus clases, y utilizar clases publicas de nivel superior en diferentes archivos.

Puedes revisar mas sobre estas clases en el siguiente [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) (en inglés)

Comment: y el voto negativo porque?